# Find PDF of random variable Y=X^2 using CDF of random variable X

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, transformation

Random variable $X$ - length of square's side. find PDF $f(x)$ of square's area.

$$X: f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{2}\sin(x), \ x\in[0, \pi] \\ 
0, \ x\in[\pi,2\pi]
\end{cases}$$

That's what I have come up with:

$f(x)$ doesn't have pdf because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{'}(x) \ne 1$

I need to find $Y=X^2$

$$g_1^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$$

$$g_2^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{x}$$

cdf: $f_Y(x)=f_X(g_1^{-1}(x)\lvert\frac{x}{dx}g_1^{-1}(x)\rvert + f_X(g_2^{-1}(x)\lvert\frac{x}{dx}g_2^{-1}(x)\rvert \ \Rightarrow f_Y(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$

pdf: $f_Y(x) = cdf(f_Y(x))$

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: $f$ is the pdf of $X$ and it does integrate to $1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I tried to solve it that way from the very beginning but the answer is wrong because f_Y(x) = 0 and integral of f_Y(x) != 1. Am I trying to solve it wrong way?

Comment: $\int_0^x \frac12\sin(z)\, dx= \frac12(1-\cos(x))$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$, and when $x=\pi$ this is $1$.  If $Y=X^2$ then $F(y)=P(Y \le y) =P(X \le \sqrt{y})$ which is easily found when $y \in [0,\pi^2]$ and its derivative is not much harder

Comment: @Henry I got the idea, thank you very much!